# A synonymous phrase for "compute statistics"

Tags: verb-forms

which is the appropriate verb relative to "compute statistics"?
I write this but I need a synonymous in order to not repeat the same word.

thank you

Comment: What about "Calculate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider :

1. **Measure**
2. **Calculate**
3. **Tally**
4. **Estimate**
5. **Determine**
6. **Survey**
7. **Valuate**
8. **Evaluate**

I'm not very certain what your context is, so I've listed out a few **possible** synonyms.